# Does there exist an opposite to curve length in integral calculus, "radius length"?

Tags: calculus, geometry, soft-question, curvature, arc-length

Consider the formula for curve (arc-) length in integral calculus:

$$\int_a^b\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2}dx$$

What would the geometrical opposite thing to measure be? Some kind of leaping curve-radius? I imagine allowing a normal line for every point on the curve:

$$y=kx+m, \\ k = -\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\\ m = f(x)-kx$$

And then finding some radius which maps our function down to a shortest radially displaced function in some sense. Simplest example a circle would give constant radius and one point in the middle for any point on the arc.

How could this be made more formal?

---

I have been thinking about some optimization problem. Since in the normal lines above, $k$ and $m$ are decided for each $(x,y)$ for $y=f(x)$. Then we can build a system of lines equations minimizing 2-norm should give us (endpoint,radius) pairs.

Comment: What you describe looks like the [evolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute).

Comment: A "curve" is not a circle.  It doesn't have a single "radius".  But there is, at each point on the curve, a "radius of curvature": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes I think this is quite closely related concept to what I was thinking. Evolute seems to be function following successive crossing of these lines, where I am searching for something that pushes these successive crossings closer together by allowing "temporal radius" (length of normal line to new function) to vary over the function.

Comment: Well, the evolute is just the locus of the centers of curvature, so the points are on the normal to the original curve, at a distance which is the radius of curvature (inverse of curvature). It's of course possible to choose a different distance, but you'll have to find out the equation of the new curve (should be similar to the evolute, except that the "radius" is some function you choose). How is that related to "opposite of curve length" though?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Curve (arc) length is measured along the curve, along $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$. We want to measure change of locus in orthogonal direction $-\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$. In some sense "opposite", no?